# Passing parameters to a partial view using Html.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing an MVC application (razor syntax), and I am having issues passing parameters into my `Html.Action` call. Below is a search page I am implementing. Note, the model contains distinct values to be used in the dropdowns.

Call From View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, null)){

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.siteCode)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.siteCode, new SelectList(Model.siteCode), "All")

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.group)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.group, new SelectList(Model.group), "All")
}

@Html.Action("ShowOrderData", "Home", new {siteCode = Model.siteCode, group = Model.group}
```

Action in Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowOrderData(string siteCode = "",
                                        string group = "",)
{
        var model = _db.ToolOrders
            .Where(r => r.SiteCD_LOC.Contains(siteCode))
            .Where(r => r.GroupCode.Contains(group))

return PartialView("_OrderData", model);
}
```

Note: There may be some syntactical errors. There are about 10 more parameters being passed and I didn't want to clog up the code blocks.

So when debugging with this code, empty strings are sent to my *ShowOrderData* controller. I attempted to add .ToString in the Html.Action call ( `Model.siteCode.ToString()` ), and a LINQ statement will show up instead. I am guessing this method is wrong because the model does not contain any information from the previous request.

How do I properly send data from the QueryString to a partial view? I've seen methods that access the queryString directly via request.querystring, but I've also heard that it is bad practice to use that in a view.

Thanks

Comment: Are you not be able to pass parameter to your partial view action?

Comment: This is probably just a typo in your question, but you said empty strings are sent to the ShowOrderData _controller_, but your markup calls the ShowOrderData **action** on the **Home** controller. Is that correct? Regardless, it looks like you have it wired up fine (except for that typo). Are you sure Model.group and Model.siteCode have values when the ShowOrderData action is called?

Comment: You are correct with your typo assumption. I realized that the model I am utilizing only contains distinct values for use in the dropdown filter boxes, and NOT the values from the QueryString (filter choices from previous request). I have implemented a temp fix using Request.QueryString["columnName"]. I have read that this is bad practice, so I wish to learn the proper method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  @Html.RouteLink()
```

instead of action

Comment: Via MSDN: Returns an anchor element (a element) that contains the virtual path of the specified action.
I need the partial view to be rendered here, not a link to it. I don't think RouteLink does this. Correct me if I'm wrong..